# Unable to Serialize JSON to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, yamldotnet

I have an issue with JSON serialization into a class with a dictionary property.
The whole process is a bit more complex, as an input i have a YAML file that i convert into a json using `YamlDotNet` and `NewtonSoft` [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364884/how-to-convert-yaml-to-json)

This is an example of the Yaml and the JSON output

```
some_element: '1'
should_be_dic_element:
 - a: '1'
 - b: '2'

{
 "some_element": "1",
 "should_be_dic_element": [
  {
   "a": "1"
  },
  {
   "b": "2"
  }
 ]
}
```

And the class

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "some_element")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "should_be_dic_element")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
 }
```

I know the issue with Array dictionary so this are all the things I've tried.

Using Dictionary i get the following

> error Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array

Using a new class from Dictionary like so

```
[JsonArray]
class X : Dictionary<string, string> { }
```

> error Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key

Using `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` / `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` the outcome is the amount of elements but with null values.

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your JSON which you are attempting to de-serialize is not conforming to your class definition.  Try changing the way you are generating the JSON.

For a dictionary-type structure, I would expect to see curly braces `{` instead of `[` to begin the structure, e.g.:

```
{
 "some_element": "1",
 "should_be_dic_element": {
  {
   "a": "1"
  },
  {
   "b": "2"
  }
 }
}
```

If you want to deserialize the existing JSON unchanged, try using your class definition to specify a list of dictionaries as such:

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "some_element")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "should_be_dic_element")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Dictionary { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: You are correct, this is not the ideal dictionary json representation yet it is possible to do. many articles are talking about it this is why i used JsonArrayAttribute on the derived class. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676125/json-array-to-c-sharp-dictionary/43676283

Comment: please see the updated answer, you should be able to de-serialize this way but your code to process the data may be a little more cludgy as a result.

Comment: Thank you :) but this is the solution i am  trying to avoid.